# Core data error about "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation."

Tags: iphone, core-data, icloud, crash-reports

I've gotten this crash log from many customer reports, and I am sure that it isn't caused by Core Data migration because I have added the following:

```
NSError *error;

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
//NSError *error;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
    ASLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}    

return persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

I got this crash log in a recent version, and I found that all of these crashes occur on iOS5.0.1. 
I guessed that it was caused by iCloud backups, that Apple deleted the user's sqlite file since I stored the local data file in Documents directory, but the user told me that he didn't open iCloud, so I can't figure out the root cause. Any suggestions or advice is very, very welcome. Help is greatly appreciated!

And I can't reproduce this crash issue on my side even with the same environment.

Comment: Did you make versions of your core data model? Are you sure you first created a new version of the model, set that to the active version, and then made changes to that new version? Because making changes to the previous version could break the migration

Comment: Hi Cardinal, Thanks for your comments. I created new version, such as newcoredata2 without space between newcoredata and number 2, I don't know if that is root cause, I have set active version as 2, I didn't changes to previous version. I can't reproduce this issue on my side, but that occurs on some of my customer.

Comment: I got the root cause about this issue, since NSManageObjectContext is not thread safe. I use the same NSManageObjectContext in other thread. Hope this can help others.

Comment: @G-Power Are you sure the problem was due to NSManageObjectContext being not thread safe. I am also face the exact same issue of random crash with this error.